# error with inserting a table into a database I created in python using sqllite

Tags: python, sqlite

Everytime I try to create a table in the datable I created titled 'tutorial' I get an error. Here is my python code :

```
import sqlite3

conn=sqlite3.connect('tutorial.db')

c=conn.cursor()

def create_table():
c.execute("CREATE TABLE example(Language VARCHAR , Version REAL, Skill TEXT)")


def enter_data():

     c.execute("INSERT INTO example VALUES('Python',3.3,'Intermediate')")
     c.execute("INSERT INTO example VALUES('Python',2.7,'Beginner')" )

     c.execute("INSERT INTO example VALUES('Python',3.4,'Expert')" )
     conn.commit()

   enter_data()



  #conn.close()
```

And here is the error that appears when I run the code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Pentazoid/Desktop/Become a professional python programmer/Section 2 web python programming/insert_data.py", line 19, in 
>       enter_data()
>     File "C:/Users/Pentazoid/Desktop/Become a professional python programmer/Section 2 web python programming/insert_data.py", line 13, in enter_data
>       c.execute("INSERT INTO example VALUES('Python',3.3,'Intermediate')")
>   sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: example

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you're not executing `create_table()` , so the table is never created and `enter_data()` can't find it when trying to insert.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the function to create the table and commit BEFORE the insert statement:

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('tutorial.db')

c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE example(Language VARCHAR , Version REAL, Skill TEXT)")


def enter_data():
    create_table()
    conn.commit()

    c.execute("INSERT INTO example VALUES('Python',3.3,'Intermediate')")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO example VALUES('Python',2.7,'Beginner')" )

    c.execute("INSERT INTO example VALUES('Python',3.4,'Expert')" )
    conn.commit()

enter_data()
```

However, consider to use SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 0):

execute `create_table()` first in command line for creating table (as was said in above) . Then add `enter_data()` for inserting.